# Nyquist stability Range of K

Tags: control-system

Here is a block diagram representation of a control system.  By using the Nyquist stability theorem how may I find the range of K which makes the closed-loop system stable?

[image]

I have found that:
The poles are s=-4,-5

if y is output and x is input:

y/x=[G(s)G(s)]/[1+G(s)+G(s)G(s)]

## Message from Andy aka to Stephen Harvard

please don't delete this question. Undelete it to get decent help but don't throw the towel in as soon as you get frustrated.

---

Anyway - here's the help I would have provided in an answer: -

### A little help

Start with a slight redraw of your block diagram: -

[image]

So, can you solve what is inside the green box?

If you can then you have, in effect, two green boxes in cascade with the purple box being replaced by the identical green box.

Can you take it from here to get something like this: -

[image]

Comment: Solving the block diagram mathematically is a start.

Comment: How may I solve that?

Comment: @StephenHarvard Find the total transfer function between the input and output of your block diagram.

Comment: I couldn't find that. If I could then I would not be here asking.

Comment: @StephenHarvard Please, show us what you have tried by editing your question.

Comment: I have edited now, showing all I have managed to find